# Thread rendez vous monitor

Tags: c, posix, mutex

I'm trying to implement a rendez vous with monitor and mutex, but it's not really working. I hope you can help me to see the issue.  Here's the code:

```
void traitement_principal(){
    if(iRdv==NB_RDV){
        iRdv=0;
        continuer=1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&autoContinuer);
    }else{
        continuer=0;
    }
    while(continuer!=1){
        pthread_cond_wait(&autoContinuer,&emAffichage);
    }
    printf("Thread %lu, je finis mon traitement mon traitement \n",pthread_self());
}

void* traitement(){
    pthread_mutex_lock (&emAffichage);//demande accès
    printf("Thread %lu, je commence mon traitement \n",pthread_self());
    iRdv+=1;
    traitement_principal();
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&emAffichage);//rend accès
    pthread_exit((void *)NULL);
}

void thdErreur(int codeErr, char *msgErr, void *codeArret) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d soit %s \n", msgErr, codeErr, strerror(codeErr));
    pthread_exit(codeArret);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int etat;
    pthread_t idThd[NB_THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i <  NB_THREADS; i++){
        if ((etat = pthread_create(&idThd[i], NULL, traitement,NULL)) != 0)
            thdErreur(etat, "Creation thread avec rdv",NULL);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++)
        if ((etat = pthread_join(idThd[i], NULL)) != 0)
            thdErreur(etat, "Join threads afficheurs", NULL);
    printf ("\nFin de l'execution du thread principal \n");
    return 0;
}
```

`NB_RDV` is a macro that expands to `3`.

`iRDV` is a file-scope variable initialized to `0`.

`continuer` is a file-scope variable initialized to `0`.

Here is an example of the program oputput:

[image: sample]

It is not what I wanted.  For example, for the first ones, I would like to get

```
Thread 0 I start
Thread 1 I start
Thread 2 I start

Thread 0 I end
Thread 1 I end 
Thread 2 I end
```

Comment: It would be much easier to read your code if your logs were in english.

Comment: commence = start / finis = end

Comment: The code you show is incomplete.

Comment: English please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most significant problem in your code appears to be that `traitement_principal()` calls `pthread_cond_signal()` when the `iRdv` counter reaches `NB_RDV`.  This will wake *one* thread waiting on the condition variable, but you need to wake multiple threads.  To achieve that, you should call `pthread_cond_broadcast()` instead.

But if you want to reliably wake exactly `NB_RDV` threads and allow them to proceed, then you have a further problem.  After the thread that broadcasts to the CV releases the mutex, you cannot be confident that the the just-woken threads will all re-acquire it before any other threads waiting on it acquire it.  If a thread that was waiting in `traitement()` acquires it first then that thread will enter `traitement_principal()` and reset `continuer` to `0` before the woken threads proceed, causing the latter to resume their wait when they eventually reacquire the mutex themselves.

If it's ok for *any* `NB_RDV` threads to proceed past the barrier after that number have reached it -- maybe including threads that reach it after the `NB_RDV`<sup>th</sup>, then you can achieve that with a few modifications.  Instead of implementing `continuer` as a flag, make it a counter whose value at any given time indicates how many more threads may proceed past the rendezvous without (further) waiting.

On the other hand, if you need to ensure that the first `NB_RDV`<sup>th</sup> threads to arrive at the rendezvous are also the first to leave, then I think you'll need to add some form of shared state tracking their order of arrival.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed, I saw the issue after I used the broadcast. I will try to do it the way you said with a counter but in fact what's annoying is that I thougth there was a function with condition to see if the condition is empty of waiting threads. But I can't find any information on this.

Comment: No, @Minirock, Pthreads has no function for testing the number of threads waiting on a condition variable.  But you can wrap such a counter together with the condition variable in your own data structure, which indeed is roughly what you have done.  This serves your particular purposes here, but it is less generally useful than you might think.

Comment: Looks like there is full of differences with what i saw in class. Things like in theory monitor should be able to implement mutual exclusion by them selves....but in fact in C we have to implement this using mutex...always in theory, the teacher tolds us there was a function on condtion like cond.empty telling us if a process is waiting on the monitor condition. I should keep that in mind for next times.

Comment: Well yes, @Minirock, there is frequently a difference between theory and practice, and the theoretical constructs you study, such as monitors, may furthermore map imperfectly to the actual tools available to you.  In particular, the Pthreads library does not provide monitors at all.  It instead provides the separate components of a monitor -- mutual exclusion locks and condition variables -- directly.  You can build your own monitor from those or use them (at least the mutexes) independently.